# Transactionscope timeout with less than 1 minute

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this situation:

```
try
{
    if (log.QuantidadeTentativa <= 3)
    {
       using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            try
            {
                logIntegracaoRepository.LimpaMovimentoCancela(log.DataInicio, log.DataFim, log.ShoppingId.Value);
                ObterDadosDoServicoNeposFull(log, shopping);
                movimentoCancelaRepository.GravaMovimentoCancela(log.Id);
                scope.Complete();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                scope.Dispose();
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Here I have 3 steps inside a transactionscope. The first one is to delete rows in database through a procedure.

The second step is to get xml data from a service and insert them in a couple of intermediary tables,

The last step is to move those data from intermediary tables to other ones as a definitive data.

Those steps works fine if I do not use transactionscope. If I use it, the second step throws an time out exception.

I have done almost everything is possible, without success. I can´t change machine.config cause I do not have this permition at client server.

I have used the line below without success too. In this line, I set the time out period. Have use up to 2 hours, but the error persists.

```
int timeToScope = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ScopeTransactionTimeInSeconds"]);
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeToScope)))
```

The only problem is this transactionscope... I really don't know more what to do.

Comment: Make sure you don't use distributed transactions. 

Distributed transactions occur when you have several transactional data sources, like to different databases or the same database, but you use different connection strings to access them

Comment: HI, I am using just one database with just one connection string. I have looked at my services in dev machine and the MSDTC is running. I have not tried to run without it running. And I have another player is this scenario. I am using entity framework. Do u know if it is a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Your timeout is probably failure to connect to MSDTC. Unless you are using the same db connection, the second db roundtrip will escalate it to a distributed transaction.

Distributed transactions are managed by MSDTC on both the local system on the DB server. If the db server is in a different domain than the server where your code runs, it will fail to authenticate. You can see this in the windows event log if that is what's happening.

Likewise, if MSDTC is not running on both machines, or a firewall is blocking COM RPC calls, etc it will also fail.

If you want to avoid MSDTC altogether, keep the db connection around and reuse it for all db operations within the transactionscope..

Comment: Hi, I am using just one database, just one conn. My scenario has another player. I am using EF 5 to access database. So, I dont know can I configure my connection to avoid MSDTC and use the same connection. Any Idea ?

Comment: Create the connection first thing in the transactionscope and pass it to the methods... ...then, create your DbContext or ObjectContext using the constructor that take an existing connection as a parameter:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696604(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: ...and link to the MSDN doc for the ObjectContext constructor you're looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738714(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't use distributed transactions. Distributed transactions occur when you have several transactional data sources, like to different databases or the same database, but you use different connection strings to access them.

If you have to use distributed transactions make sure to enable them.

The Distribution transactions are run by "Distributed Transaction Coordinator" services in Windows services. By default it is stopped and has Manual start mode.

Comment: I think I am using MSDTC cause the service is running in my dev machine. I have not tried run my project without the service. I suppose it will get an error. I would like to know if there is a way to use the same connection with EF 5 and transactionscope. Is there a way ?